# dynamic link to view page

Tags: views, routes

So i have set up a page view which has the path about/% with % representing the argument used in that view. I now want to link to this page on the main navigation bar.

I created a menu item  about/%dest but that didnt work as i guess the route is already registered by the view? so i altered it to look like this:

```
$items['%dest/about']= array(
  'page callback' => '_bps_path_redirect',
  'page_arguments' => 'about',
  'title' => 'about',
  'title callback' => 'get_title',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
);

function dest_to_arg() {
  $arg = arg(1);
  return $arg;
}

function _bps_path_redirect($arg) {
  drupal_goto($arg.'/'.arg(1));
}
```

But to no success, the redirect doesn't work. So am i missing something? Is there a simple way to link a view which has a wildcard in its path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I modified the page views to use a static path and then set up a contextual argument to grab the parameter of the url to use as an argument.